# Access C# variable in js script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

In the past I've accessed variables from other java scripts by doing

```
static var somevar;
```

In one script. And in the other:

```
 OtherScript.somevar;
```

But I need to access a variable from C# code in a js script. I've tried:

```
Public static bool somevar;
```

In the C# file and in the js file:

```
OtherScript.somevar;
```

But I get the error: Unknown identifier 'somevar' in the js file

Comment: Perhaps looking for this tutorial: http://www.41post.com/1935/programming/unity3d-js-cs-or-cs-js-access

Comment: I ended up just rewriting the script in unityscript

Answer (score 0):

Just put your Unityscript file in the `Plugin` or in the `Standard Assets` folders.

---

**Explanation:**
In the "standard" way, you can only access a Unityscript variable from a C# script, but you cannot do the opposite. That's just C# code is compiled before Unityscript's one.

So, in order to achieve what you are trying to do, you must move your Unityscript file into a "special" folder (in Unity, they are the `Plugin` and the `Standard Assets` ones), so that it would be compiled at first.

After that, you should achieve the access with the usual logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a Static Object from JS and call its properties. You would have to get help from Unity GameObject to get the Object as Component as everything is an ObjectComponent in Unity. Then use that Component(Technically the Script) as your reference.

Example

GameObject name is "MyCsharpGameObject" <- the GameObject that has the Script

Then use.

```
theCscharpscript : OtherScript;
theCsharpscript =  GameObject.find("MyCsharpGameObject").GetComponent("OtherScript");
```

On usage from the JS

```
theCsharpscript.thevariable;
```

Remember when using JS in MonoDevelop it doesn't give you Intellisence and that is just Normal. You can't however access a Static "Class" that is not attached to a GameObject.

if you insist on doing so. Then check Andrea's Answer. But his explanation might be complicated for you to work on.

But summing up the point that he was saying is. C# works in a NameSpace and JS is not part of that NameSpace so at lease you will have to somewhat include it in, and NameSpace is nothing more than a Folder Location in an Project. Simple as that.

However you must always remember to use PragmaStrict in this as it will always be transformed into a MonoDevelop calls even though you did not Extend from it.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help but with theCscharpscript : OtherScript; I get the error OtherScript does not denote a valid type ('Not found')

Comment: theCscharpscript : OtherScript; <- You put this in JS. Make sure of that. It is not in C#.

Also Make sure that OtherScript is the name of the class aswell as the name of the C#Script File.

Comment: I am pretty sure I did that but I ended up rewriting the c# script in js. Thanks for your help though.